# Keep same height for all tabs even with border

Tags: html, css

I got a tab list, it must take the entire width up to 1024px, and tabs should take equal space. Problem is I need to set a border on the active tab and when the active tab label has only one line of text, the tab item has a different height than the ones where their label has multiple lines.

Tabs should have always the same height, so the border jump generated by this issue doesn't happen. I need a CSS only solution for this, preferably without using a fixed value for tabs height. These elements are being modeled as components and they need to have generic styles. The tab list is using `display: flex` and I've been trying to solve the issue with flexbox properties but couldn't get anything this far.

**html**

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}


/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  // transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.tabcontent {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  /* Fading effect takes 1 second */
}


/* Go from zero to full opacity */

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London<br>City</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo<br>City</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZzBoK

Comment: you should include the code in addition to the codepen link (some people wont click it ) I added it for you

Comment: @happymacarts You are correct. That said, you can make use of SO's inline snippet tool to include a runnable snippet in the question instead of just the code.

Comment: i left the code only since he has it in a codepen but yes i usually use the snippets

Comment: @happymacarts Good! Consider it a note for OP then :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your .button border transparent on default, and then set a color for it when activated.

```
.tab button {
    ...
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    ...
}
```

and then

```
.tab button.active {
    ...
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrNNOY

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    // transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

.tabcontent {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s; /* Fading effect takes 1 second */
}

/* Go from zero to full opacity */
@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London<br>City</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo<br>City</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically solve this problem by setting a transparent border on all the tabs, then setting a color for the active tab.